# Why is $\frac{1}{\ln2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}p(z)\ln \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}dz=\log_2e[\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2]$?

Tags: probability, integration

This is part of the derivation of entropy of a Gaussian $Z$

$p(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Why is $$\frac{1}{\ln2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}p(z)\ln \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}dz=(\log_2e)\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)\right)$$? I can't understand here.

It should become $$\ln \sigma\sqrt{2\pi} \times 1 \times \frac{1}{\ln2}=\frac{\ln \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}{\ln2}=\log_2 \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}$$

Comment: Have you tried integrating at all?

Comment: i add the result of integrating all

Comment: Please use `\ln` and `\log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the two results are the same.

$$\begin{align}
(\log_2e)\cdot\frac12\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) & =\frac{\ln e}{\ln 2}\cdot\ln\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}\\
& =\frac{\ln\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}{\ln 2}\\
&=\color{red}{\log_2\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}
\end{align}
$$

which is your answer.

Actually, your result is simpler and more beautiful :)